# how to exit a node from mysql clustering galera

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, galera

I'm using galera mysql clustring.
I have 3 nodes on 3 virtual machines as `master`.
ubuntu server is running.
node 1 and node 2 is shutdown and I only access to node 3 with ssh.
now I want to run this mysql node as a remote mysql conneciton.
how to change this config?

```
systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.35 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf, override.conf
     Active: activating (start) since Sun 2022-11-27 21:06:06 +0330; 12h ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 601851 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 601863 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 601866 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, st>
   Main PID: 602158 (mysqld)
     Status: "WSREP state transfer ongoing, current seqno: 1131170 waited 45541.000000 secs"
      Tasks: 7 (limit: 48160)
     Memory: 527.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
             └─602158 /usr/sbin/mysqld --wsrep_start_position=1f8146c8-1825-11ed-8421-47d88112f937:1131170
```

I got this error message:

```
WSREP state transfer ongoing, current seqno: 1131170 waited 45541.000000 secs
```

and mysql command:

```
 mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "node as a remote mysql conneciton".

Comment: @RickJames mysql server working as a standalone.

Comment: You are dissolving the cluster?  Or briefly removing one node from the cluster?

Comment: @RickJames I want to dissolving the cluster.

Comment: Has `wsrep` been changed to `OFF`?